# scrbook and synctex don't work together

Tags: forward-inverse-search, scrbook

I have a larger document that uses `scrbook` as a basis. Since the doc is long, I rely on SyncTeX for direct and inverse searches. However, there are lots of parts in the document I can't jump to.

I wrote a mini-micro version of the `synctex` command and see that the problem is that the `synctex` libraries don't seem to find the file name for some of the tags:

```
./sy main.pdf 3 144 72
[tag:1] /Users/paag/Documents/Projects/NetIDE/netide/Documents/Work-packages/WP2/Deliverables/D2.1/./main.tex line 193
./sy main.pdf 17 144 72
[tag:74] (null) line 1
./sy main.pdf 18 144 72
[tag:74] (null) line 1
./sy main.pdf 19 144 72
[tag:74] (null) line 202
```

When the filename is not null, I can jump from the PDF to the source with Skim on MacOSX and Evince on Linux. However, when it is null, I cannot.

As said, the test program cannot be more stupid :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "synctex_parser.h"

#define  SYNCTEX_SCANNER_PARSE 1 // set to 0 to call  synctex_scanner_parse() explicitly

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
synctex_scanner_t scanner;
char cwd_buffer[1024],*cwd, *pdf_file;
int page,xoffs,yoffs;

if (argc == 5) {
    pdf_file = argv[1];
    page  = atoi(argv[2]);
    xoffs = atoi(argv[3]);
    yoffs = atoi(argv[4]);
} else {
    printf("usage %s <pdf_file> <page> <xoffs> <yoffs>\n\n",argv[0]);
    return -1;
}
/* TODO: extract base directory from pdf file name */
cwd = getcwd(cwd_buffer,1023);

scanner = synctex_scanner_new_with_output_file(pdf_file, cwd, SYNCTEX_SCANNER_PARSE);

if (scanner != NULL) {
    if (synctex_edit_query(scanner,page,xoffs,yoffs)> 0) {
        synctex_node_t node;
        while((node = synctex_next_result(scanner))!=NULL) {
            int tag           = synctex_node_tag(node);
            int line          = synctex_node_line(node);
            const char *fname = synctex_scanner_get_name(scanner, tag);
            printf ("[tag:%d] %s line %d\n", tag, fname, line);
        }
    } else {
        printf("synctex_edit_query failed!\n");
    }
} else {
    printf("new synctex scanner not created!\n");
}
synctex_scanner_free(scanner);
}
```

Comment: I disagree a bit: I'm inclined to search the mistake in the code of your file. Could you paste somewhere the logfile of your book?

Comment: Check that no names of included files or (sub)directories contain a space or an eight bit character. Also, I get problems with synctex if the combined file and folder name is very long ( I have not found the exact length). Move the book-folder and its subfolders to a temp-directory at the root of your harddisk (c:\temp on windows), and recompile.

Comment: Moving the project to /Users/home/temp didn't help. Any suggestion where to put the log file?

Comment: @PedroA.Aranda Any news here? Best to ping somebody using the `@`-notation.